# How do I programmatically change value of a field in an Access database?

Tags: database

Let's say I have a list of names in an Access table. I add one column called Found with default value No/False.

What I want to do is to search through the names via a query and set the Found value to Yes/True if the name contains 'abc'. How do I do this?

I envision something like this: do while name contains 'abc' set Found to Yes.

Thanks for helping a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create query as follow:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyTable.Found = True WHERE MyTable.NameField LIKE "*abc*";
```